# Well, I declare! (dictionary says it's used for 'surprise', what's the meaning of this sentence?)

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> Well, I declare!

Why does this expression mean 'surprise' and in what context could this expression be used?

Comment: I declare [that I am surprised], the last part being omitted because it is a standard expression and native speakers know that. Also this is rather regional (southern USA).

Comment: Well, ah do declayuh, Dep'ty Dawg!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Dep'ty? What's that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deputy_Dawg

Comment: It is a rural expression and somewhat old fashion.

Comment: There are other similar idioms, such as "I say!" I think the meaning is pretty obvious, as Michael Harvey says, although the question about context, how old it is, where it is used, etc, could be interesting.

Comment: Curiously, although the *literal* meaning of ***I [do] declare!, I say!*** seems to be the *opposite* of ***I'm lost for words!, I'm speechless!***, all those expressions are used in much the same context (speaker wants others to know she's ***astonished***, but doesn't actually know how to articulate any more coherent response).

Answer (score 1):

I would dispute Michael's assertion that it is an expression peculiar to the southern USA. I'm quite familiar with it even though I'm British and know little about the 'Deep South'. Oxford Languages gives:

*Well, I declare — an exclamation of incredulity, surprise, or vexation.*

*"‘Well, I do declare! It's Annabelle!’"*

The sense is "I declare that [this surprising fact] is true!" or, in the context of vexation "I declare that [this annoying thing] has happened!"

Comment: *Well, I never!* - are you really saying you converse with people who use ***I declare!*** non-facetiously today? It's one thing to be *familiar* with a usage (from books, movies, etc.), but quite another to actually move in circles where that usage occurs "naturally" in the real world. I still occasionally hear people say ***I say!*** in certain contexts, but I doubt I've ever  heard ***I declare!*** "for reals".

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's rather old-fashioned (though Oxford doesn't say so), but I certainly wouldn't think of it as regional.

Comment: Well, I think it's a *very* "marked" expression today - the primary feature being that it's *old-fashioned*, but to the extent it still occurs "in earnest" at all today, I'd expect that normally to only be in specific sociolinguistic or regional "pockets".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I met an (very) old lady in Bath about 30 years ago, and when I said I had been stuck in a traffic jam for 2 hours, she said 'Well, I never did!'. I was saying that for weeks, and still do, now and then.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: My grandmother used to say ***Well, bless my soul!*** But she was just a year short of her century when she died 20 years ago. If I heard anything like that from a non-native Anglophone aged under 70 today, I'd take it for granted they didn't learn English from a "normal" source.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have a pal who was what people called a 'young fogey', only now he's a proper old one. A member of the Victorian Society. He says things like 'Lawks!' and 'Lumme!'. At one time one might detect a faint ironic nuance, but that has, I fear, quite vanished. Any time I fear I am old-fashioned, I think of him and realise that I still have some way to go.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I still say ***Land sakes and lawks a-mussy**!* myself now and again, but it's *always* facetious. On the other hand, I once had to live with my grandmother for a few weeks before being able to move in to my first house purchase, and by the time I left I found I'd got in the habit of saying ***Fiddlesticks**!* (instead of my normal f-word) quite "naturally".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have been known to say **fiddle-de-dee**. Maybe I am a fogey.

Comment: At least we're a bit more articulate than the up-and-coming generation - who only know how to pick which one of a dozen emojis accurately conveys everything they've got to say! :)